# Application of Jensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis

1. Let $T \in \mathbb N$. Since sqrt is concave, why is $$ \sqrt{T+1}
       \leq \sqrt{T} + 1? $$ isn't this contrary to Jensen's inequality?
2. let $p \in (-1,0)$, what is the convexity of $f$ defined as $f(x) =
       x^p$? Is  $$ (T+1)^p  \leq T^p + 1? $$

Thanks.

Comment: Does "concave" mean "convex downwards" for you?

Comment: convex as in Jensen's inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Statements

Comment: @Timbuc Convex and concave are classical and unambiguous terms. I have no idea which one "convex downwards" or "concave backwards" shall mean. (Sometimes, one can guess from context, but not always.) I wish those neologisms would die a quick and violent death.

Comment: @Tim Don't forget the weights, $$\sqrt{\frac{T+1}{2}} \geqslant \frac{\sqrt{T}+1}{2}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, I've always thought that the "upwards", "downwards" terms **precisely** remove the amibiguity. Concave and convex, on the other hand, may be pretty misleading...but I guess it is only a matter of agreement (or lack of)

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's right. The measure should be a probability measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if

$$\;f(x)=\sqrt x\implies f'(x)=\frac 1{2\sqrt x}\;,\;\;f''(x)=-\frac1{4x\sqrt x}<0\implies$$

$\;f(x)\;$ is convex downwards, and thus

$$\forall \,t\in[0,1]\;,\;\;\sqrt{(1-t)x+ty}\ge(1-t)\sqrt x+t\sqrt y$$

So you having $\;\sqrt{T+1}\le\sqrt T+1\;$ contradicts nothing.

For $\;x^p\;,\;\;p\in(0,1)\;,\;\;x>0\;$ , we have

$$f'(x)=px^{p-1}\;,\;\;f''(x)=p(p-1)x^{p-2}<0\implies f(x)$$

is convex downwards, and thus

$$((1-t)x+ty)^p\ge(1-t)x^2+ty^p$$

**Added:**  Define for $\;x>0\;$ the function

$$f(x):=(1+x)^p-x^p-1\;,\;\;-1<p\le0\implies f'(x)=p\left((1+x)^{p-1}-x^{p-1}\right)>0$$

since

$$(1+x)^{p-1}<x^{p-1}\iff x^{1-p}<(1+x)^{1-p}$$

and thus $\;f\;$ is monotone descending , which means

$$f(x)\ge\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0\;,\;\;\forall x>0$$

and we're done

Comment: So are the two inequalities in my question not because of Jensen's ineq? Are they correct then?

Comment: Seems so, @Tim ...

Comment: But the real kicker is that if the "convex thingwards" stuff should make any sense at all, then I would expect $f$ being "convex upwards", since the "upward side" of the graph is convex.

Comment: @DanielFischer Upwards  seems easy to be easily and satisfactory defined: in the direction of the positive $\;y$- index. But as said: it is a matter of agreement.

Comment: Thanks. How do you prove my second inequality? @Timbuc?

Comment: @Tim,  check the added stuff to my answer.