# Condition on $f$ for $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Are there inequalities about $f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$?
Specifically, conditions on $f$ for it to hold?

What about $f(x+y) \geq f(x) + f(y)$?

Examples:
I am looking for the general (as general as possible, like Jensen's inequality etc) case for why the two inequalities hold in [Application of Jensen's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1053173/1281)

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity

Comment: That's right. I am looking for some inequalities that say some functions are subaddtive or superadditive.

Comment: Appears to be an ordered Homomorphism.

Comment: maybe look at convexity/concavity...